# How i could take id articles from Ajax for django

Tags: python, django, ajax

i take id product and try to go view django, and always took error
how i could take data in view? help pls

i don't understand what data i get from request and how can i look inside

```html
$(function () {
  $(".js-take-id").click(function () {
    alert("вы нажали на кнопку скрипта Poka! с номером товара id="+ $(this).data("id"));
    const csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
});
    $.ajax({
      url: '/articles/',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        'id': $(this).data("id"),
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```
class MainArticles(ListView):
template_name = 'dishes/articles.html'
model = Articles

def post(self, request):
    name = request.POST.get('/articles/')
    #data = json.loads(request.POST.get('data'))
    data = json.dumps(request.POST.get('/articles/'))
    return HttpResponse('HelloWorld')
```

Comment: `def post(self, request):
        name = request.POST
        a = dict()
        for i in name.keys():
            a[i] = name[i]
        print(a)
        return HttpResponse('HelloWorld')`
but is this the wrong approach?

sorry i can't make the code smooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/articles/',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    'id': $(this).data("id"),
  },
   success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
});

class MainArticles(View):

def get(self, request):
    articles_list = Articles.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'dishes/articles.html', {'articles_list': articles_list})

def post(self, request):
    name = request.POST['id']
    data = list(Articles.objects.values().filter(id=name))
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

cheers, finally, the solution to my simple ajax request looks like this, if there is a newbie here, here it is
though I still don't know how to use the data from the js that I sent, if a js expert is here, tell me how to display a description from my queriset